# How advanced and/or important would aircraft be for a species capable naturally of decent to good flight?

Tags: technology, technological-development, flight, travel, aircraft

I am wondering how a species capable naturally/supernaturally(with limits) of decent to good flight, i.e capable of flying for hours and possibly can hover, would treat aircraft like passenger jets and the like.

I mean we, for the most part, can walk/run, but we still have tons of cars and buses and other similar vehicles.

Would there be as much use of aircraft as their is now? Would their use be more limited to very long-distance travel, cargo, and leisure?

Like would there still be as much use of commercial airliners as now or would folks fly with their own 2 wings(or more) and airliners being more lightly and less frequently used?

Would people use light aircraft similar to how some ride bikes if they have no car?

I have been asked to give how long an average member of said species can fly and how much they can lug around in flight. For sake of this example, imagine humans with working bird wings that can fly around 40-60 MPH, for at least 8 or so hours, and can carry around 1 of their bodyweight in flight.

That being said, the only species with a society  that can fly that I have(so far) are cockroaches around like 3/4-1 inch in size, so maybe take fliers like them into consideration.

Comment: You never specified how much weight they can carry or how fast or far they can fly: the two main reasons we have cars and busses when we can still walk or run.

Comment: @DKNguyen That looks like an answer -- and should be one.

Comment: @DKNguyen That is kind of hard to say since flight speed and strength vary greatly between species. Let us say that these flyers are 5-6 feet tall, use bird wings to fly, can fly at like 40-60 MPH, can fly with like around 1x their bodyweight, and can fly for as long as the average person can walk/jog, so like a good chunk of the day(8 hours maybe).

Comment: @ConanHighwoods These things sound super human. People can't walk, let along jog carrying their own body weight fir 8 hours. How do these things take off? But still, 1x body weight is useless for a lot of cargo in an industrialized society. And sometimes weight isn't even the issue, it's bulk. Though people on motorcycles and bicycles can carry impressively volumous loads, but that volume matters a lot more when you're flying at 50mph because drag.

Comment: So maybe more like 1/2-3/4 for average flier. @DKNguyen

Comment: I mean, unless his birdpeople are literally Superman, those specifics are unlikely to change the answer: mechanical flight will always improve all aspects of what the biological species can do. If anything, the problem seems to be that the answer to this question is a little too obvious and uninteresting, and is contained pretty well entirely in DKNguyen's comment. (Posting answers as a comment! 10 yard penalty! Repeat first down.)

Comment: you can walk how big was the invention of the car , truck and train

Comment: @ZeissIkon Those were also the first questions that came up when I read the Q. Since when is asking for "details, please" answering the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The automotive Industry would be affected, but not the airline industry

Vehicles have 3 main purposes, and as long a vehicle can fill at least one of these functions, they can still be a worth while investment of resources.

1. They get us where we want to be faster.
2. They allow us to carry more stuff where we are going.
3. They allow us to travel with less exertion.

When talking about "good flight over several hours" you are probably talking something comparable to a migratory bird like a duck or something of the sort.  An average migratory bird can sustain speeds of about 40-60mph for hours on end with some able to travel as far as 800 miles in a single day!  The reason airliners are not threatened by this figure is because cars already average over 60mph over long distances, and 800 mile road trips are not uncommon. Cars also allow you to carry more stuff than you could as a flying bird, and it's a lot less excusing to drive for hours on end 'cus you literally just sit there as you move.

So if cars in our world can meet or beat birds in every key metric, and we still have a major demand for an airline industry, then any other intelligent being that can make modern airplanes will prefer them over natural flight at least as often as we prefer them over our cars.

That said, the automotive industry would see a significant impact. I still think a lot of people who own cars now would still own a car, but households with more than 1 car would be a lot more rare.  Most people like owning cars for thier ability to transport stuff.  They can pick up groceries, transport children, move furniture, etc.  All of these demands will still exist for your avion people, and cars and trucks will still be WAY better for this than natural flight, but time will be less of a consideration for your flying folk.  Getting around the city when all you need to bring is yourself will be much more convenient to do by wing than by car; so, going to work, heading to your favorite dinner, etc. will be so easy to do without a car that you will see the need to have more than 1 car pretty much disappear.  The value of mass transit systems like buses and trains will also go way down with most commuters not needing to drive or be driven to work every day, the number of riders that would want to use mass transit would go way down, and the total traffic will be much lower such that urbanized areas will not be so obligated to use it to reduce traffic congestion.

If mass transit is not a viable business model in your world, then perhaps some of the reduction of multi-car household could be offset by more people needing cars at all for basic day-to-day transportation stuff... either that or you'd see it replaced by a much larger taxy and delivery service industry.

### A Minor Possible Exception

The only places you will see the airline industry negatively effected is when looking at bodies of water between about 50-100 miles across.  Places like the Aegean Sea or Lake Superior are too wide to build bridges over, but would not take a bird a very long time to cross; so, in our world, these places may see unusually large amounts of airline activity over relatively short distances where natural flight might edge out the airline business a bit because "as the bird flies" it's not very far... but these differences are so geographically specific that it would not have a major impact on the airline industry as a whole.

Comment: This answer is good, but if their flight is that good, would not airliners take a hit? Maybe they would just take them for going to another country? Maybe because most fliers take luggage with them and flying naturally with that is hard? Or just because it is less tiring, as you stated earlier?

Comment: @ConanHighwoods Compared to our world, no.  Because migratory bird flight is worse than a car by every metric.  People generally don't take airplanes for flights of less than 250 miles specifically because anything closer is more convenient to drive to anyway.  For a Migratory bird, that is either a 5 hour natural flight or a 20 minute trip on a 747.  So even if you waste an hour or so going through the airport, it's still a huge time and convenance saver before you even start to consider things like luggage.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fascinating question. The more I think about it the more things spring to mind that would change. Not just in aviation (I'll get to that in a moment) - but literally the entire structure of civilization.

Case in point - if you go to an area that still maintains rural towns, you'll notice that most of them are around 20-30 miles apart. This is curiously the distance that a horse and rider could be expected to travel in a single day.

Whereas being able to fly at 60 mph for 8 hours gives a range of 420 miles - how we build cities would be drastically different.

I'm not sure we would bother with Roads or roading infrastructure:

*because the reason we used to carry goods in bulk was due to the time it took to get there* - walking with a backpack or walking with a horse and cart took the same time, so may as well load up more goods in one trip.

Whereas with an ability to fly, we would likely make smaller, more frequent trips because we can travel faster.

Would we even invent shipping? Possibly - but again the initial driving factor might not be there.

I think we would see a civilization that is significantly more spread out in terms of distance between cities, the expectation of time and travel distance would be baselined at what the average flying human can do in a days travel.

Consider the following - If you told a young person of today (read this next bit in a Yorkshire accent for the full Monty Python effect) about how long it used to take to order a package from Amazon and that it could sometimes take Months to get something from the Internet - they wouldn't believe you and they wouldn't accept that degree of slowness today (okay, I'm exaggerating a teensy bit for dramatic effect - but you get the idea).

Once we've gotten used to (as a society) a certain degree of service, it's really hard to convince people to suffer a bit of inconvenience for something that *might* in the long run be better.

In addition to this (Yes, I will get to the answer soon, I promise) - one of the biggest driving forces behind the cost of Air Travel would also significantly change: Safety.

Consider the early car - they were unreliable as anything - and if it ground to a halt, you pulled over to the side of the road and walked. Air Travel, however, has a major difference - if it goes catastrophically wrong in mid-air - you're dead. However now, if it goes wrong - well no worries, everyone jump out the back and we'll glide the nearest land mass.
We would also have a conception of positioning in 3D space from flying at a young age - meaning a Pilots licence would be about as difficult as a drivers licence.

Now I've outlined all of this:

Air Travel would be cheaper because of the reduced cost of safety engineering as an Individual can survive a catastrophic failure in mid-air.

The cost of maintenance for an Aircraft would be significantly lower because the lowered risk of death from a failure (so pre-emptive parts replacement wouldn't be as necessary)

Air Travel would have a significantly lower barrier to entry as everyone would have the fundamentals of traversing a 3D space (and the aforementioned Safety aspect isn't a factor).

Our cities would be much more spread out and so the main function of Air Travel would be high-speed, long distance (much like today).

I'm not sure we would have any meaningful form of Ground Transport or infrastructure as it would be difficult to convince people to accept a significantly slower speed in terms of time to transport goods in bulk, when winged carriers could do it faster and cheaper.

Comment: I agree that roads would be much less likely to be a thing, but you would probably still get canals and then railroads for bulk goods transport.

Answer (score 0):

You never specified how much weight they can carry or how fast or far they can fly: the two main reasons we have cars and busses when we can still walk or run. So the answer I guess is: Yes.