# How would having decent/good/great ability to fly naturally affect a species air, land, and water vehicle creation and usage?

Tags: civilization, flight, transportation

I had posted a similar question about this not too long ago, only it was just asking about aircraft. It got closed for whatever reason. I am asking a similar question, because I realized that air-travel is pretty much the superior form of getting around, and hence would effect the 3 main types of crafts, not just aircraft.

Basically, how would the ability to fly decently, good or great inherently change what types of vehicles are made and how they are used by a civilization.

Here are the 3 point that need answering:

1. Effects on creation and usage of aircraft(airplanes, helicopter, etc.)
2. Effects on creation and usage of landcraft(buses, bikes, cars, etc.)
3. Effects on creation and usage of watercraft(boats, ships, etc.)

Now, I understand that not all things fly the same or as long. Some fliers can hover and others cannot, some go for a mile or so at most, some hundreds of miles at a time. I also understand that environment is also everything as well.

For the sake of this question, let us assume that these fliers are roughly mansized, can hover and can fly at 40-60 MPH for several hours a day. They also should be able to fly with upto like 1/4-1/2 of their bodyweight. Their world is Earth/Earthesque.

So how would mass transit vehicles like buses, jets, and ships fare? Would folks use than as often as our world does? How would things like fishing or going to work or school play out? How about shopping?

If need-be, I can give more details.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed too for failing the "book test" and having insufficient details - a book can be written just on the development of a single type of vehicle, let alone a class of vehicles.  As far as details go - in order for a mansized creature to be able to fly as described their metabolism must be supercharged, which means they need massive amounts of food - but how much?  You are asking us to design their settlements and then design ALL transport infrastructure and vehicles - too much!

Comment: 1. Ok, I will give you that one as I am being kind of vague, to be fair though, this only because I want this to be a general guide, not a species specific thing.                                2. Creatures as big or bigger than a man have flew, they are called pterosaurs.                 3. I just want to now how their relationship with vehicles, not how their whole iv is like, you are just making it more hard than it has to be.                                                  @KerrAvon2055

Comment: Creatures as big as a man have flown, but you specified that they can "hover" - that takes an extraordinary amount of energy and I do not believe it has ever been suggested that pterosaurs were capable of it.  Take out the ability to hover and specify a single location (eg "area with climate and geography identical to New York state") and a single year-equivalent technology level and it might be specific enough to be answerable.  Answering across all of history and all of a planet, from deserts to rainforests, from tropics to poles, is far, far too broad.  (continued)

Comment: We also need to know if the physiology of the creatures will impact vehicle design - how much can they fold up their wings?  Can they fly with wet wings or is the ability to move around when it is raining a good reason to use vehicles?  Some information on reproduction and maturation is needed too - if there are clutches of six offspring who cannot fly until they are in their teens then the need for vehicles is much greater than if infants can fly when they are one or two days old.

Comment: They only hover for like 10-30 seconds max and they start to fly around the same time humans first learn to walk. They are humanoid.@KerrAvon2055

Comment: When your Posted similar question got closed 'for whatever reason' will you please either cite that reason, or drop all reference to that incident? Is that choice not fair?

Comment: Did you get my message about the mutant roach? I added that info in the post, you did rea my question in full, right? @RobbieGoodwin

Comment: Yeah, I should have said why. I needed to clarify it. Note that it had been open for a few days and had like 2-3 answers, 1 accepted by me, so it was a bit odd for them to close it. @RobbieGoodwin

Comment: I feel I already addressed this in your previous question with my answer - in short - cities and towns that historically have been spread out by the distance of an average day's ride on a horse would be spread out by the distance of an average days flight - and then there are a massive load of implications from there: see https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/244339/how-advanced-and-or-important-would-aircraft-be-for-a-species-capable-naturally for reference

Comment: @TheDemonLord, not necessarily.  These avian people might be able to fly 300 miles in a day, but to get their produce to market, they will still rely on roads and wagons.  Those distances between waypoints care a lot more about caravans carrying trade goods than they do about the random traveler.

Answer (score 1):

**Creatures Are Too Tired**

Since they have not much need for the vehicles, they may just use them when they are tired (or lazy)

**What About the Unfortunate?**

Like how some people need motorized scooters, they developed vehicles just so those creatures who are disabled/handicapped

**Who Will I Move My Junk and Stuff?**

In the end, vehicles could be developed just for carrying cargo and shipments that may be too much just for one species.

Comment: To add to point number one, I know plenty of humans who will drive anywhere that takes more than 5-10 minutes to walk to, even if it's perfectly within their comfortable walking distance.